# Are women only scholarships legal under Irish / EU law?

Tags: european-union, discrimination, ireland

As a student of a software engineering course I tend to receive tech related emails. Over the last year I've received 3 scholarship related emails of which all were titled with something along the lines of

> Women in technology scholarship

I noticed for the first 2 emails, when I clicked on their links, their webpage showed a list of criteria and were very careful with what they were demanding of their applicants.

> Applicants **must** be graduating in year XX/XX
>
> Applicants **must** be enrolled in a computer science or related degree

etc. etc.

But it is when they get to the gender/sex criteria, it is usually described as the following:

> This scholarship is **open** to female applicants

The third email had this as part of their criteria

> Applicants must **identify** as female

My question is; under Irish or European law, is it in any way illegal to advertise or hold scholarships with any of the criteria I've described?

Comment: I think that under UK equality act which I would guess could be analogous to EU laws, this would qualify as "positive discrimination" and thus be unlawful.